# Error about billed CPU time when set Hello World Smart Contract

Tags: smart-contract

My VM Spec (VMWare ESXI)

CPU : Xeon CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz
Memory : 8GB
HDD : 70GB

EOS 1.5.3 , EOS.CDT 1.4.1 Compile from Source Code with AutoBuild Scripts.

I try to create first smart contract according to Tutorial Document.
https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/your-first-contract

It show some error like these picture below.
[image]

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every action, including setting a contract for the account, consumes some amount of CPU resource.

Try staking or delegating more of the core token to CPU resource of your `hello` account.

Answer (score 1):

Now I try again and then work successfully.
It seem that my VM have performance's issue so I will check it again.

Thank you so much for your help.

[image: Try Again]png